# Redis: redis-cli not asking for password

Tags: authentication, redis, redis-sentinel, redis-cli

I have configured my `redis.conf` with `requirepass` and I started the server with

```
redis-server redis.conf
```

However, when I run `redis-cli` it does not ask me for password
and lets me connect to redis, but when I try to run a command, asks me for the password.

This behavior is causing problems with Sentinel because Sentinel tries to authenticate. Sentinel won't find that master because is not asking for password.

Answer (score 0):

https://medium.com/garimoo/redis-sentinel-no-such-master-with-specified-name-fatal-config-file-error-1ca8b3d25d38

Wasn't something releated to redis-cli i associated two separate things
there is the solution.